# Error on installing Ruby on Rails on a Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed Ruby, latest version.
I have installed XCode, latest version.
I have installed CommandLine tools for XCode too.

Then I want to install Ruby on Rails, but I got the following error:

> Fetching: json-1.7.5.gem (100%) Building native extensions.  This
>   could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing rails:     ERROR: Failed
>   to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make compiling generator.c make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: Please paste the contents of /Users/JonyIve/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out so we may get a better idea as to what went wrong here.

Comment: Please show the actual command you use.  Presumaby rvm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I had this problem when I was setting up rails env on newly installed 10.8 mac. Command Line tool was installed, but gcc is still missing. 
I refereed to some blog posts: (i.e. [Beryllium Work](http://blog.berylliumwork.com/2012/09/missing-gcc-42-in-mac-os-x-108-when.html)) that recommended to create link to the location that the make script is looking for:

```
bash> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
bash> sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.2
```

I think this solved my problem on installing rails